# How to solve circular dependency in model definition in node?

Tags: node.js, model-view-controller, mongoose, ecmascript-6, circular-dependency

I'm following MVC architecture using express and mongoose and I came upon an issue with circular-dependency. The code itself is written in **ES6**.

I have these two particular models (keep in mind that I obscured these models as much a possible):

Destination model, which contains information about all available rooms:

```js
// destination.model.js
import mongoose, { Schema } from 'mongoose';
import Booking from './booking.model'; // eslint detect dependency cycle here
import Room from './room.model';

const DestinationSchema = new Schema({
    id: { type: Number, required: true },
    name: { type: String, required: true, max: 100 },
    description: { type: String, required: false },
    rooms: [Room.schema]
});

DestinationSchema.statics.getAvailableRooms = async function (startDate, endDate) {
    const bookings = await Booking.find({ 'room._id': room._id });
    // do something with these bookings
};

export default mongoose.model('Destination', DestinationSchema);
```

and Booking model, which is in relation many to one with Destination.

```js
// booking.model.js
import mongoose, { Schema } from 'mongoose';
import Destination from './destination.model';
import Room from './room.model';

const BookingSchema = new Schema({
    id: { type: Number, required: true },
    client: { type: String, required: true },
    startDate: { type: Date, default: '' },
    endDate: { type: Date, default: '' },
    room: { type: Room.schema, required: false },
    destination: Destination.schema
});

export default mongoose.model('Booking', BookingSchema);
```

**Main issue:**
ESLint detects dependency cycle in destination model (and in booking model) - which is present. The reason for that, is that I have a static method in Destination model, which looks over all Bookings (and possibly might call a static method in the future).

My question (or actually looking for an advice) is, how do I handle this issue? I come from Ruby on Rails background, so I'm really used to having both instance and static methods defined in a model, with single file.

I don't want to separate methods into another file and I would like to keep them in single file - is that possible in any way or should I really go for file separation?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I think you should model booking schema like:

```
const BookingSchema = new Schema({
    id: { type: Number, required: true },
    client: { type: String, required: true },
    startDate: { type: Date, default: '' },
    endDate: { type: Date, default: '' },
    room: { type: Room.schema, required: false },
    destination: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Destination',
    },
});
```

Comment: okay, this might solve this particular problem - however what if there's a static method in Booking model that uses Destination model?

Comment: what prevents you from doing that?